# Posts not working on windows after changing permalinks

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I recently started learning wordpress. Out to curiosity of changing settings, I changed permalinks to Month and Name. After that all my posts and pages have stopped working and show me a 404 Error. I am not being able to figure out why is it happening.
I even tried posting new posts and even they doesnt work.
Please suggest any solution. I am using WP 3.7 on windows machine with wamp.

Comment: It should be not getting an error. Have you try to change your theme and deactivated the plugin (in case you activated it)?

Comment: Theme is default twenty thirteen. I tried changing it to twenty fourteen. But didnt help. There's no active plugin. Its a new fresh wp installation. Thing is when I change permalink to default it starts working.

Comment: @ucon89 there is probably no problem with the theme or plugin, but some .htaccess files doesn't allow you changing permalinks, and that gives indeed an error 404

Comment: can we see your htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In wamp you have to manually click/unclick an option to change the .htaccess(and allow permalinks with that).

To do this , click the wamp icon on your (windows) task bar, choose apache > apache modules and check 'rewrite module'

Comment: Thank u so much.... That worked for me.... Will give you a plus once I have enough reputation..

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your `.htaccess` file. Try going into the permalink settings and saving them again just to be sure. If it warns you that the `.htaccess` file has not been updated, you will need to either change the permissions, or update it manually.