# Changing permalink settings causes 404

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I would like to have permalinks of the form `http://localhost/mysite/sample-post/`. I tried to achieve this by changing the permalink settings in the admin panel to 'Post name' from default. But this causes 404: page not found error.

I've tried with the other settings e.g., month and name, numeric etc. but all of them results in 404. The generated URL is changing according to the permalink setting though.

Clearing the cache did not help either.

Does something else need doing here ? Thanks.

Edit:

My server: lamp on ubuntu 12.4 lts

Contents of the .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What is in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: are you using wamp, xamp or a diffrent server?

Comment: If you are using wamp, try this -> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129981/posts-not-working-on-windows-after-changing-permalinks/129986#129986

Comment: @Maartje, I'm using lamp

Comment: Have you gone through all the helpful information in the documentation for [setting up permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)?

Comment: @s_ha_dum, I've edited my question to show the contents of the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities: you may need to enable mod_rewrite on the Ubuntu server or check/fix permissions to allow Wordpress to write to the .htaccess file.

Best thing to do is read http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks and work through suggestions.